# Get filtered co-occurrences from a sparse matrix

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy, nlp

I have a scipy csr sparse matrix (a document-term matrix created with scikit-learn’s CountVectorizer).

The matrix is huge (78M tokens across 9.5M documents):

```
<9482138x78045191 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
with 394161806 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I want to reduce the matrix so that it contains only some of the tokens (columns). I have these in a list, and can extract them into a new matrix like this:

```
tokenarrays = []
for tokenid in tokenids_we_want[:3]:
    tokenarray = dtm.getcol(tokenid).toarray()
        tokenarrays.append(tokenarray)
```

Maybe there is a better way, using some kind of filtering method.

My end goal is a co-occurrence matrix of the wanted tokens. As a first step towards this, I have created a pandas dataframe using:

```
pd.DataFrame(zip(tokenids_we_want, tokenarrays))
```

This does not result in one pandas column per token in the tokenarray, however.
There is probably a better way altogether to do what I need:

- Start from a sparse document-term matrix
- Keep only some of the terms (tokens)
- Get term co-occurrences

Comment: Can you do `dtm[:, list_to_extract]`?  That is just do a matrix column indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, it works! The final step would then be to get the term co-occurrences based on the new smaller dtm.